# How to set a list defined in model with a list from view page:yii 1.1

Tags: model-view-controller, yii

I have passed a list '$passValue' from my controller to my view form . Now i have to set this list into $emailList which is also a list defined in my model.How it can be done?
My code of view form is:

```
<?php 
    $val=array();
    foreach($passValue as $par){
    array_push($val,$par);  
    }
    echo $form->hiddenField($model,'emailList ',$val,array('size'=>50,'maxlength'=>50,'readonly'=>'readonly')); ?>
```

My js code :

```
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '<?php echo CController::createUrl('client/sendMail'); ?>',
        data:{ids:selectbox},
        dataType:'json',
        success:function(data){ 
        if (data.status == 'failure')
            {
            $('#dialogMail div.divForForm').html(data.div);
               }
           },
        error: function(data) { 
         alert("Error occured.please try again");
          }
    });
```

My controller code to open my dialog:

```
if (Yii::app()->request->isAjaxRequest)
    {
        echo CJSON::encode(array(
            'status'=>'failure', 
            'div'=>$this->render('_compose', array('passValue '=>$passValue ,'model'=>$model), true)));
        exit;               
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can assign value using html options. But here you are trying to assign an array. first you need to change the array in string and then you can assign. Use json_encode for change the array to string or implode function to convert array in string.

```
<?php 

      echo $form->hiddenField($model,'emailList',array('size'=>50,'maxlength'=>50,'readonly'=>'readonly','value'=>$val));

     ?>
```

Comment: You can assign value using html options. But here you are trying to assign an array. first you need to change the array in string and then you can assign. Use json_encode for change the array to string or implode function to convert array in string.

Comment: <?php 
    $val=array();
    foreach($passValue as $par){
    array_push($val,$par);  
    }
$val=json_encode($val);

  echo $form->hiddenField($model,'emailList',array('size'=>50,'maxlength'=>50,'readonly'=>'readonly','value'=>$val));

?>

Comment: it is not working .i get error message. i have used js to pass my parameter.When i simply pass $val my form is opening.Now error message from js appears

Comment: There is issue in your controller as you are calling other view file. If this is ajax request then use renderPartial in place of render

Comment: if (Yii::app()->request->isAjaxRequest)
    {
        echo CJSON::encode(array(
            'status'=>'failure', 
            'div'=>$this->renderPartial('_compose', array('passValue '=>$passValue ,'model'=>$model), true)));
        exit;               
    }

Comment: ok i was able to set the my model with desired list but my list is something like "0"=>["abc@yahoo.com","def@gmail.com"]".I want my model value like "0"=>"abc@yahoo.com";"1"=>"def@gmail.com";

Comment: If you want to use the field as an array then set type of this in your model file. And then there is no need to change the array into string using json_encode. just pass array.

 array('emailList','type','type'=>'array','allowEmpty'=>false),

Comment: i tried your answer. Again "Error occured.please try again" message appears